# Change DateTime in the Microsoft Visual Studio debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, datetime

What the.... How do I change the value of a DateTime in the debugger?  I can change it, but I get an error when leaving the edit field; it cannot parse it.

Edit: VS 2008, C#

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Without looking at what you have, I'm not really sure what edit field you're referring to. However, you could try using the immediate window and `DateTime.Parse` or `new DateTime()` instead.

Comment: For instance in the watch window; a DateTime will show as {03/12/2009 00:00:00}, but if I change e.g. the date to 04 instead of 03, I get an error from VS: Invalid expression term '{'

Comment: Thanks (also you, astander), that's what I needed.  Although I think it sucks :-)  The debugger should support that.

Comment: slugster's answer has an example of how to use this answer: Just type the following in the _Immediate_ window `myDate = new DateTime(2009, 12, 25)`

Comment: immediate windows doesn´t work, when you want to set an datetime in an object, that is declared by an interface, but the interfaces doesn´t have that property.

Answer (score 46):

You can change the date in the Immediate Window.

```
date = new DateTime(2009, 10, 05)
{05/Oct/2009 12:00:00 AM}
    Date: {05/Oct/2009 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 5
    DayOfWeek: Monday
    DayOfYear: 278
    Hour: 0
    Kind: Unspecified
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 0
    Month: 10
    Second: 0
    Ticks: 633902976000000000
    TimeOfDay: {00:00:00}
    Year: 2009
```

Comment: If date is not readonly ... but he is asking for changing the value of a DateTime ... your solution is to change the reference. The answer should be - you can't, because it is immutable, isn't it?

Comment: Date is immutable, but this creates a new date object which you can assign to the variable you want to change.

Answer (score 19):

We do can change a DateTime value directly in the Watch Window. The trick is simple: we always have to use a "new DateTime()" method, providing the appropriate parameters.

The Watch Window do not allow you to to type a new value directly, so things like "2010-07-13 9:15" or even {13/07/2010 09:00:00} don't work.

Comment: You can do this hovering the mouse directly over the variable without having to use the Watch Window. It works in Visual Studio 2012. I don't know about previous versions.

Comment: Thank you, using new DateTime(...) did the trick! This was a member of class, and "token.expiry = new Datetime(...)" in the immediate window failed with "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Answer (score 14):

You can do it if you define your DateTime between parenthesis.

```
(new DateTime(2017, 09, 27))
```

Comment: Your answer is totally right, direct, and avoiding to waste time and taking the question to another fields, you get my vote

Answer (score 12):

You can type things like this in to the Immediate window, the Watch window, or the QuickWatch window and they will get evaluated:

```
myDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2)
myDate = new DateTime(2009, 12, 25)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean on Visual Studio debugger try like this:
- set the breakpoint
- open your DateTime variable in QuickWatch for example (right click)
- in Expression text box enter new value, this is example if your variable name is "dt":
   dt = dt.AddDays(3)
- press enter and continue executing project

Answer (score 0):

The "dt = " portion isn't strictly necessary. Just type in "dt.AddDays(3)" or "new DateTime(...)" or DateTime.Parse(""), etc, and the debugger will try to assign whatever value results from the expression you type to the variable under watch; it just so happens that because C# has assignment expressions (e.g. y = (x = 1); //sets y = 1) that assigning the expression to the variable name works. :)

Comment: Signatures are considered bad form. Please read the FAQ for details.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy option (non generic) =>

In the **Value** input inside *watch window* for example
Type `DateTime.Now` then press enter

Et voilà ! :)

Answer (score -1):

You can change the non-public data-value in miliseconds in debugger mode, to change it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).